# Vue CLI ESLint injects additional whitespace into multi-line spans

Tags: html, css, vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm outputting a list with a project set up using the VUE CLI and all the defaults it provides and working in VSCode.

I've got a list I want to put at the end of a string. If I write the code like:

`<span v-if="fruits">(<span v-for="(fruit,index) in fruits" :key="index">{{fruit}}<span v-if="index != (fruits.length - 1)">, </span></span>)`

then it shows up like `(orange, banana, strawberry)` which is exactly what I want.

But when I apply the ESLint formatter, it wants to turn the code into this:

```
<span v-if="fruits">
  (
  <span v-for="(fruit,index) in fruits" :key="index">
    {{fruit}}
    <span v-if="index != (fruits.length - 1)">, </span>
  </span>)
</span>
```

This is far more readable and I like it, except that the result turns it into `( orange , banana , strawberry )` which is very much not what I want.

How do I remove those extra spaces being inserted while not disabling ESLint and keeping the formatting it applies?

I'm relatively new to web development and I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, but all the other answers I've found on this topic are to apply CSS rules that change the margin on the text, and I just want to delete the extra space.

I initially switched to the javascript `.join` method, but realized I will need to wrap each fruit with it's own span to apply a css class.

Comment: Two potential workarounds I've stumbled across: 

Have the formatter ignore the line. Using the defaults, I found https://github.com/Prettyhtml/prettyhtml#ignore-element and <!--prettyhtml-preserve-whitespace--> worked. 

There's also this potential one of using a directive. https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7701#issuecomment-368249629

Neither of these feel like a solution, just a bandaid over something going wrong upstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to the Prettier formatter which will preserve your whitespace but create this mess:

```html
  <span v-if="fruit"
    >(<span v-for="(fruit, index) in fruit" :key="index"
      >{{ fruit }}<span v-if="index != fruit.length - 1">, </span></span
    >)</span
  >
```

Or you can escape the format rules by ignoring the single-line loop:

```html
<!-- eslint-ignore-next-line -->
<span v-if="fruits">(<span v-for="(fruit,index) in fruits" :key="index">{{fruit}}<span v-if="index != (fruits.length - 1)">, </span></span>)</span>
```